# Automatically fill a cell according to the next cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Consider having two cells right beside each other, e.g. A1 and A2!

Now, I want cell A2 show me a name according to which value I enter in cell A1!

For example, if number "1234" was entered in A1, the A2 cell would show "Alice", and
at the same exact cell, i.e. A1, if "5678" was enter "Bob" would show up and vice versa.

Now, I know that it can be done with IF function for only **one** argument bit not for several values!

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a data table that defines each number you enter as a name.

Like 1234 in one cell and then Alice in the cell next to it

Once you have that for all of the names and their corresponding values, you should be able to put the following in cell A2

```
=XLOOKUP($A$1, C:C, D:D)
```

Where column C is the column containing the numbers that correspond to the names and column D is the column containing the names corresponding to the numbers.

[image: Image shows example and includes function for cell A2]

Hope this helps!